# How can access the random numbers using Random.Range( ) from different script?

Tags: arrays, random, unityscript

I'm stuck at this very simple lines of code in Unity2D using C#. Simply i just want to access a random number generated from a different script.

```
//Script A
void Start(){
    int rand;
    rand = Random.Range(0,4);
    myString1 = myArray[rand];
}

//Script B
public ScriptA obj;
public string[] myString2;
public string nj;
void Start(){
    myString2 = new string[] {
        "A" ,
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
    };
    nj = myString2[obj.rand];
    guiText.text = nj;
}
```

Everything works just fine, my GUIText Shows, my Random no is generated perfectly in Script A, but when i does access it in Script B, it return 0 only i.e only A, even if the random generated number is 2 or 3, it prints A in GUIText.

Trust me i just sorted problems within my project,but still it doesn't behaving the way i wanted to be.

I mean seriously, GUIText shows only A, i need A,B,C & D randomly..
Plz anyone help me with these..!!

Answer (score 0):

The variable rand is only accessible locally in void Start() for Script A.

Try this in Script A

```
public int rand {get; set;}
void Start(){
    rand = Random.Range(0,4);
    myString1 = myArray[rand];
}
```